# Como exibir somente o valor da variável no progress

Tags: lógica, progress-4gl

to criando um programa e gostaria de exibir apenas o valor da variável no Display sem o nome, tem como fazer isso ?

```
DISPLAY "Nota Fiscal do dia" vDia "do mes"vMes "do ano de"vAno .
```

existe algo tipo `vDia.getValue()`? algo do tipo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por padrão quando você utiliza o DISPLAY, ele trás o Label da variável,
para não mostrar, utilize...

DISPLAY variavel NO-LABEL.